# error TS2339: Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, angular-services

Here is my code in book.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Book } from './book';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

//import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import 'rxjs/add/operators/catch';
//import 'rxjs/operators/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class BookService 
{
    url = "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/books.json";

    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> 
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
                .pipe(map(this.extractData))
                .catchError(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
    getBooksWithPromise(): Promise<Book[]> 
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
    }
    private extractData(res: Response) 
    {
        let body = res.json();
        return body;
    }
    private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) 
    {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        //console.log("Error in Observable");
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
    private handleErrorPromise (error: Response | any) 
    {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }   
}
```

And I m getting the Error here:

> ERROR in src/app/book.service.ts(26,18): error TS2339: Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Well the Error is in 26th line and that is :

```
.catchError(this.handleErrorObservable);
```

I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked... Can anybody solve this?

Did with 'catch' but didn't work, so then I go for 'catchError' but still, there is this error...

Answer (score 15):

`catchError` needs to be imported and then used within `.pipe`:

```
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'; 

return this.http.get(this.url)
            .pipe(
              map(this.extractData),
              catchError(this.handleErrorObservable)
            );
```

Comment: path incorrect `import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators`

Comment: @Krack Depends which RxJS version you're on.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use it inside `pipe` like this:

```
getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
             .pipe(map(this.extractData),catchError(this.handleErrorObservable));
}
```

Comment: Ya got it bro ! done with it ... Thank you so much, btw :-)

Answer (score 2):

`catchError` must be inside `pipe`.

```
 import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
 import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

 getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> 
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
                .pipe(
                   map(this.extractData),
                   catchError(this.handleErrorObservable)
                 );                    
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to change to:

```
...
return this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((r:Author)=>console.log("GOOD"),err=>console.log("ERROR))
...
```

it is an issue of rxjs